# mybatis select latest primary key after insert record in PostgreSQL 13

Tags: java

I am insert a record into PostgreSQL 13 using MyBatis, this is the insert define:

```
<insert id="insertSelective" parameterType="com.dolphin.soa.post.model.entity.Users">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
    -->
    <selectKey keyProperty="id" order="AFTER" resultType="java.lang.Long">
      PostgreSQL
    </selectKey>
    insert into users
    <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
      <if test="nickname != null">
        nickname,
      </if>
      <if test="avatarUrl != null">
        avatar_url,
      </if>
      <if test="phone != null">
        phone,
      </if>
      <if test="updatedTime != null">
        updated_time,
      </if>
      <if test="createdTime != null">
        created_time,
      </if>
      <if test="salt != null">
        salt,
      </if>
      <if test="pwd != null">
        pwd,
      </if>
      <if test="sex != null">
        sex,
      </if>
      <if test="level != null">
        `level`,
      </if>
      <if test="phoneRegion != null">
        phone_region,
      </if>
      <if test="countryCode != null">
        country_code,
      </if>
    </trim>
    <trim prefix="values (" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
      <if test="nickname != null">
        #{nickname,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="avatarUrl != null">
        #{avatarUrl,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="phone != null">
        #{phone,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="updatedTime != null">
        #{updatedTime,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
      <if test="createdTime != null">
        #{createdTime,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
      <if test="salt != null">
        #{salt,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="pwd != null">
        #{pwd,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="sex != null">
        #{sex,jdbcType=INTEGER},
      </if>
      <if test="level != null">
        #{level,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="phoneRegion != null">
        #{phoneRegion,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="countryCode != null">
        #{countryCode,jdbcType=INTEGER},
      </if>
    </trim>
  </insert>
```

but when execute the insert action, shows this error:

```
Caused by: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error selecting key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: PostgreSQL
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:92) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:440) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:271) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.insertSelective(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.user.UserService.add(UserService.java:44) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.user.UserController.setPwd(UserController.java:96) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error selecting key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: PostgreSQL
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.SelectKeyGenerator.processGeneratedKeys(SelectKeyGenerator.java:90) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.SelectKeyGenerator.processAfter(SelectKeyGenerator.java:54) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:51) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy157.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor.invokeUpdate(DefaultTimeInterceptor.java:93) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor.intercept(DefaultTimeInterceptor.java:55) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor.invokeUpdate(DefaultTimeInterceptor.java:93) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor.intercept(DefaultTimeInterceptor.java:55) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:49) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at misc.interceptor.db.DynamicDataSourceInterceptor.intercept(DynamicDataSourceInterceptor.java:86) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:184) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: PostgreSQL
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.toolkit.ExceptionUtils.mpe(ExceptionUtils.java:39) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.parser.AbstractJsqlParser.parser(AbstractJsqlParser.java:74) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.handlers.AbstractSqlParserHandler.sqlParser(AbstractSqlParserHandler.java:76) ~[mybatis-plus-extension-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.plugins.PaginationInterceptor.intercept(PaginationInterceptor.java:155) ~[mybatis-plus-extension-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy157.prepare(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:87) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor.intercept(PageInterceptor.java:111) ~[pagehelper-5.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:49) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at tk.mybatis.orderbyhelper.OrderByHelper.intercept(OrderByHelper.java:115) ~[orderby-helper-0.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.SelectKeyGenerator.processGeneratedKeys(SelectKeyGenerator.java:67) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    ... 109 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.JSQLParserException: null
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parseStatements(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:128) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.parser.AbstractJsqlParser.parser(AbstractJsqlParser.java:60) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    ... 147 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "PostgreSQL" <S_IDENTIFIER>
    at line 1, column 1.

Was expecting one of:

    "("
    ";"
    "ALTER"
    "BEGIN"
    "CALL"
    "COMMENT"
    "COMMIT"
    "CREATE"
    "DELETE"
    "DESCRIBE"
    "DROP"
    "EXEC"
    "EXECUTE"
    "EXPLAIN"
    "INSERT"
    "MERGE"
    "REPLACE"
    "SET"
    "SHOW"
    "TRUNCATE"
    "UPDATE"
    "UPSERT"
    "USE"
    "VALUES"
    "WITH"
    <K_SELECT>

    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.generateParseException(CCJSqlParser.java:20951) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.jj_consume_token(CCJSqlParser.java:20798) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.Statements(CCJSqlParser.java:475) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parseStatements(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:126) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    ... 148 common frames omitted
```

I am guessing maybe the PostgreSQL not support select key action. so what should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within **mybatis** the sql parser **JSqlParser** is used. The last cause **Encountered unexpected token: "PostgreSQL" <S_IDENTIFIER>** of your exception shows that mybatis wants to parse a generated SQL that cannot be parsed using this version of **JSqlParser**.

First, it would be helpful to see the statement that should be parsed.
Second, **mybatis** should somehow forced to generate a different SQL.

Saying that, it could be possible that due to a invalid configuration of **mybatis** especially the one responsible for this part:

```
<selectKey keyProperty="id" order="AFTER" resultType="java.lang.Long">
  PostgreSQL
</selectKey>
```

a syntactically incorrect SQL is generated.